# Removing Noise from an audiofile Matlab

Tags: matlab, audio

I am new to Matlab. I have added some noise to an Mp3 file:

```
[a, Fs] = audioread('test.mp3');
y = a + 0.01* randn(size(a));
plot(y);
sound(y,Fs);
```

Now I want to remove the noise and play the original again. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hmm, not too sure how effectively this could be done on random/white noise. Here's a MATLAB Answers question that is similar: [Remove White Noise after adding it with awgn by Spectral Substraction method](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/502059-remove-white-noise-after-adding-it-with-awgn-by-spectral-substraction-method).

Comment: @MichaelTr7 how to make a sound noisy so it can be denoised then?

Comment: It would have to be noise centralized at specific parts of a frequency spectrum such as sinusoidal noise. Broadband noise can’t be selectively frequency filtered since it covers the entire spectrum evenly.